# Use Font Awesome Icons in CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have some CSS that looks like this:

```css
#content h2 {
   background: url(../images/tContent.jpg) no-repeat 0 6px;
}
```

I would like to replace the image with an icon from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/).

I do not see anyway to use the icon in CSS as a background image. Is this possible to do assuming the Font Awesome stylesheets/fonts are loaded before my CSS?

Comment: Glyphs from fonts cannot be used as backgrounds.  SVGs, however, *can*

Comment: @cimmanon would you mind explaining how that could apply to font-awesome

Comment: @BonsaiOak What's to explain that isn't already explained by the selected answer?  If you have a question that isn't answered by this (or any other question on SO), then ask a new question.

Comment: @cimmanon sorry for the lack of clarity.  You seemed to imply that it was possible to use an icon from the font-awesome.svg font file as the background.  However, you never said that explicitly so I'm not sure.

Comment: @BonsaiOak Yes, you *can* use an SVG as a background image, the same way you would use any other image.  However, I have not actually looked at the FontAwesome SVG to verify that it can be used in this way.

Comment: https://ohmycheatsheet.com/fontawesome/ might be helpful

Answer (score 541, accepted):

You can't use text as a background image, but you can use the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-classes to place a text character where you want it, without having to add all kinds of messy extra markup.

Be sure to set `position:relative` on your actual text wrapper for the positioning to work.

```
.mytextwithicon {
    position:relative;
}    
.mytextwithicon:before {
    content: "\25AE";  /* this is your text. You can also use UTF-8 character codes as I do here */
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    left:-5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
 }
```

**EDIT:**

Font Awesome v5 uses other font names than older versions:

- For FontAwesome v5, Free Version, use: `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"`
- For FontAwesome v5, Pro Version, use: `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"`

Note that you should set the same **font-weight** property, too (seems to be 900).

Another way to find the font name is to right-click on a sample font awesome icon on your page and get the font name (the same way the utf-8 icon code can be found, but note that you can find it out on `:before`).

Comment: This is awesome! I'm currently switching countless icons over to font awesome in a large enterprise application. This is making it way easier!

Comment: The text-equivalent of each icon is there http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: You'll have to remove &#x from the beginning and ; from the end. The font-family name is FontAwesome

Comment: ok why does text gets converted to icon when inside pesudeo content but not in real element like p or div. say if i put \f010 in content i get icon, and div i get \f010 as is... How come?

Comment: Now, how do we make it scale?

Comment: @David, it's just text, use ``font-size``.

Comment: Could anyone advise how this might work with FortAwesome icon packs? FortAwesome provides you with JS to fetch the icons paid for in your pack, however I'm guessing the CSS doesn't know about these. So when I try to use one of my FortAwesome icons it just renders as an empty square.

Comment: Just want to add that the latest version of Font Awesome have this in the docs, please refer to this page for documentation: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css

Comment: for FontAwesome v5 you need to use 
```.backspace:before {
                    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
                    font-weight: 900;
                    content: "\f55a"; 
                }```

Comment: Just a note that this doesn't appear to work with Input elements (like a submit button) since they don't seem to support :before or :after.

Comment: And if you're using Font Awesome 5 Free, then `font-weight: 900` will show the filled version of the icon (the Brands), and `font-weight: 400` will show the regular version. For instance, [this](https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=solid) and [this](https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=regular) has the same 'icon-code'. So to differ between the two, then the font-weight is used.

Comment: How do you determine what exactly the font family string should be based on the icon I want to load?

Comment: Use the cheat sheet: https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet It has all the hex codes.

Comment: for me, it is working when i put `font-weight: 900;`

Comment: Just add   `.mytextwithicon *{position:relative;}` to avoid the font in background to come upon the html elements in .mytextwithicon.

Comment: This answer brought me on the right way!
Nevertheless, assigning "content" by yourself is pretty dumb as fontawesome has all the required classes. You just have to overwrite the font for the main element as fa-css is assigning it's font to it and not only to the `::before`. Like this you can use all defined icons without parsing or looking up any code.

Answer (score 25):

Actually even `font-awesome` CSS has a similar strategy for setting their icon styles.  If you want to get a quick hold of the `icon` **code**, check the [`non-minified font-awesome.css`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css) file and there they are....*each font in its purity.*

[image: Font-Awesome CSS File screenshot]

Comment: And you just can use the classes for any element, no need to transfer any code.
Just the font for the element has to be different than for the `::before`.

Answer (score 23):

Consolidating everything above, the following is the final class which works well

```
   .faArrowIcon {
        position:relative;
    }

    .faArrowIcon:before {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        top:0;
        left:-5px;
        padding-right:10px;
        content: "\f0a9"; 
    }
```

Comment: best answer, as you can just remove a previous <i> tag from before the text you want with the icon and replace with this. And the same space is given.

Answer (score 12):

To use font awesome using css follow below steps -

step 1 - Add Fonts of FontAwesome in CSS

```
/*Font Awesome Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    //in url add your folder path of FontAwsome Fonts
    src: url('font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Step - 2 Use below css to apply font on class element of HTML

```
.sorting_asc:after {
    content: "\f0de"; /* this is your text. You can also use UTF-8 character codes as I do here */
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And finally, use "**sorting_asc**" class to apply the css on desired HTML tag/element.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this example class. and find icon content here: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

```
  #content h2:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    content: "\f007";
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I am bit late to the party. Just like to suggest another way.

```
  button.calendar::before {
    content: '\f073';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    left: -4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

`position`, `left` and `bottom` are used to align the icon.

Sometimes adding `font-weight: 600` or above also helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
#content h2:before {
    content: "\f055";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Example Link:
https://codepen.io/bungeedesign/pen/XqeLQg

Get Icon code from:
https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet?from=io

Answer (score 2):

No need to embed content into the CSS. You can put the badge content inside the fa element, then adjust the badge css. http://jsfiddle.net/vmjwayrk/2/

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x" style="position:relative;color:grey;">
  <span style="
        background-color: navy;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: .25em;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 2em;
        top: -.5em;
        right: -.5em;
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        border:solid 4px #fff;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #000;
        color: #fff;
    ">17</span>
</i>
```

Comment: "No need to embed content into the CSS". Well, in some situations it's needed.

Comment: If you don't care about progressive enhancement that's fine, but you should really keep your styling inside of a css file whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if using Sass, one can "extend" FA icons to display them:

```
.mytextwithicon:before {
  @extend .fas, .fa-angle-double-right;

  @extend .mr-2; // using bootstrap to add a small gap
                 // between the icon and the text.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the given answers don't give a real background as the fontawesome is rendered outside the bloc you want the background in.
Here is my solution to have a "real" background effect :

[image]

html :

```
<div id="bloc" class="bg_ico_outer" style="">
    <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o bg_ico"></i>
    <div class='bloc_inner'>
        <h2>test fontawesome as background</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.bg_ico {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -10px;
    font-size: 17em;
    color: green;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.bg_ico_outer{position: relative; overflow: hidden;}

#bloc{
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    background: blue;
    margin:50px auto;
}
.bloc_inner{
    position: absolute;
}
h2{color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you just need to add `content` attribute and `font-family` attribute to the required element via :before or :after wherever applicable.

For example: I wanted to attach an attachment icon *after* all the `a` element inside my post. So, first I need to search if such icon exists in fontawesome. Like in the case I found it [here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/paperclip/), i.e. `fa fa-paperclip`. Then I would right click the icon there, and go the `::before` pseudo property to fetch out the `content` tag it is using, which in my case I found to be `\f0c6`. Then I would use that in my css like this:

```
   .post a:after {
     font-family: FontAwesome,
     content: " \f0c6" /* I added a space before \ for better UI */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This seems to be the simplest solution** :-)

```
#content h2:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f055";
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```