# Font Awesome icon inside text input element

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to insert a user icon inside username input field.

I've tried one of the solution from the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css) 
knowing that `background-image` property won't work since [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) is a font.

The following is my approach and I can't get the icon display.

```
.wrapper input[type="text"] {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper input[type="text"]:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -5px;
    content: "\f007";
}
```

I have font face declared in the default font awesome css so I wasn't sure if adding font-family above was the right approach.

```
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
     src: url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
     src: url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../Font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
 }
```

Comment: What do you want to know? What is the question / error?

Comment: @allcaps Oops..I admit that there is no way to identify the error I am encountering from just looking at my original post. I edited a bit.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You're right. :before and :after pseudo content is not intended to work on replaced content like `img` and `input` elements. Adding a wrapping element and declare a font-family is one of the possibilities, as is using a background image. Or maybe a html5 placeholder text fits your needs:

```
<input name="username" placeholder="&#61447;">
```

Browsers that don’t support the placeholder attribute will simply ignore it.

### UPDATE

The before content selector selects the input: `input[type="text"]:before`. You should select the wrapper: `.wrapper:before`. See http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/gA4rx/ .
I also added the placeholder suggestion where the wrapper is redundant.

```css
.wrapper input[type="text"] {
        position: relative; 
    }
    
    input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; } /* This is for the placeholder */
    
    .wrapper:before {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        color:red;
        position: relative;
        left: -5px;
        content: "\f007";
    }
```

```html
    
    <p class="wrapper"><input placeholder="&#61447; Username"></p>
```

### Fallback

Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to store icons. Other characters are not present and fall back to the browser default. That should be the same as any other input. If you define a font on input elements, then supply the same font as fallback for situations where us use an icon. Like this:

```
input { font-family: 'FontAwesome', YourFont; }
```

Comment: Using your placeholder method works. The trouble is that normal (non-icon) text does not match the font-face of the rest of the page and is displayed as browser default serif. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to store icons. Other characters are not present and fall back to the browser default. That should be the same as any other input. If you define a font on input elements somewhere, then supply the same font as fallback for situations where us use an icon: `input { font-family: 'FontAwesome' YourFont; }`. Does this help? You can always ask a new question.

Comment: @allcaps the recommendation to use a fallback font-family for the placeholder works WONDERS!! I didn't think to change the font through a fallback. Can you update your answer to include a fallback font for future users? Thanks!

Comment: where can i find list of code. i mean fa-user to &#61447;

Comment: @Elyor: You don't need to use the html entity. If your project is UTF-8, you can just copy paste the Font awesome glyph. It will probably show up as a block in your code editor, but that is okay. You can also use one of the many online unicode-to-html-entities-convertors.

Comment: 6 ways to add an icon to an input for Bootstrap 4, or 4 ways without BS4. See my fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/tyh21Lxe/

Comment: @djibe Similar example without bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is just css. Use the browser inspector on any (bootstrap) example and only copy relevant styles.

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye As you can see in my fiddle, last examples use pure CSS or HTML + CSS techniques ( = Bootstrap free).

Answer (score 154):

**Output:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input name="txtName" id="txtName">

<span class="fa fa-info-circle errspan"></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .errspan {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

**(Or)**

**Output:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
     <input type="text" />
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .input-wrapper {
        display:inline-block;
        position: relative
    }
    .input-wrapper:after {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        content: '\f274';
        position: absolute;
        right: 6px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That was excellent tip on using font-awesome with a text box.

Comment: Is it possible to make that icon clickable?

Comment: @FrenkyB, Yes. <span class="fa fa-info-circle errspan" onclick='YOUR_FUNCTION()'></span>

Comment: Setting `z-index: 1` will make the underlying input catch the focus when you click on the icon - something you may want for instance when adding a datepicker.

Comment: Works fine for me but I didn't use `position: relative` (negative margins don't need it) nor `z-index` (as soon as the element is rendered after the input)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 33):

This answer will work for you if you need the following conditions met (none of the current answers met these conditions):

1. The icon is *inside* the text box
2. The icon shouldn't disappear when text is entered into the input, and text entered goes to the right of the icon
3. Clicking the icon should bring the underlying input into focus

I believe that 3 is the minimal number of HTML elements to satisfy these conditions:

```css
.input-icon{
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: calc(50% - 0.5em); /* Keep icon in center of input, regardless of the input height */
}
input{
  padding-left: 17px;
}
.input-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="stuff">
  <label for="stuff" class="fa fa-user input-icon"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Best answer for having the icon inside the input field, where the icon remains visible while the user types.

Comment: top: calc(50% - 0.5em) assumes your label has 1em height

Comment: @drichar - I just tested, this still works with any label height. As long as you don't vertically align the label text within the label (which isn't the default) Since it aligns to the top by default, a taller label will still work correctly. I also tested with different font sizes on the label and the input. It seems to work in all scenarios.

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly I stand corrected. I'm confusing em and rem. 0.5em is half of whatever the font size is. Great solution, I'm using it in a project (just using custom SVG, not FA, which has no font size, which led to my positioning issue, and misinformed comment)

Answer (score 26):

You could use a wrapper. Inside the wrapper, add the font awesome element `i`  and the `input` element.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-icon"></i>
    <input type="button">
</div>
```

then set the wrapper's position to relative:

```
.wrapper { position: relative; }
```

and then set the `i` element's position to absolute, and set the correct place for it:

```
i.fa-icon { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 50px; }
```

(It's a hack, I know, but it gets the job done.)

Comment: Why do we need a .wrapper there?

Comment: As I understand it, absolute elements are placed relative to the nearest 'positioned' ancestor. Position: relative means the wrapper is 'positioned' (it could also have been absolute, fixed or sticky). If you don't do this, the icon will be absolutely positioned relative to some other element higher in the dom (or if no positioned elements are found, relative to the viewport).

Answer (score 19):

No need to code a lot... just follow the following steps:

```
<input id="input_search" type="text" class="fa" placeholder="&#xf002 Search">
```

you can find the links to the Unicode(**fontawesome**) here...

[FontAwesome Unicode for icons](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

Comment: What if i am already using another font-family for placeholder? then it will not work.
Is there any way to make text "Search" in "&#xf002 Search" use custom font and unicode still uses fontawesome font?

Answer (score 8):

Having read various versions of this question and searching around I've come up with quite a clean, js-free, solution. It's similar to @allcaps solution but avoids the issue of the input font being changed away from the main document font.

Use the [`::input-placeholder` attribute](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-css3-placeholder-pseudo-element) to specifically style the placeholder text. This allows you to use your icon font as the placeholder font and your body (or other font) as the actual input text. Currently you need to specify vendor-specific selectors.

This works well as long as you don't need a combination of icon and text in your input element. If you do then you'll need to put up with the placeholder text being default browser font (plain serif on mine) for words.

E.g.
**HTML**

```
<p class="wrapper">
    <input class="icon" type="text" placeholder="&#61442;" />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    font-family:'arial', sans-serif;
}
input.icon::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

Fiddle with browser prefixed selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/gA4rx/78/

Note that you need to define each browser-specific selector as a seperate rule. If you combine them the browser will ignore it.

Comment: While it's an elegant solution, it doesn't achieve the expected behavior.

Comment: Indeed, it seems Webkit browsers are the only ones that accept `font-family` for this selector at this time. We can only hope for more widespread acceptance in the future.

Answer (score 7):

```css
.input-icon{
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: calc(50% - 0.5em); /* Keep icon in center of input, regardless of the input height */
}
input{
  padding-left: 17px;
}
.input-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="stuff">
  <label for="stuff" class="fa fa-user input-icon"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi please attach a little explanation to you solution.

Comment: This answer will work for you if you need the following conditions met (none of the current answers met these conditions):

The icon is inside the text box
The icon shouldn't disappear when text is entered into the input, and text entered goes to the right of the icon
Clicking the icon should bring the underlying input into focus
I believe that 3 is the minimal number of HTML elements to satisfy the conditions

Answer (score 6):

I found the easiest way using bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></div>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did achieve this like so

```css
  form i {
    left: -25px;
    top: 23px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    color: #29a038;
  }
```

```html
<form>

  <i class="fa fa-link"></i>

  <div class="form-group string optional profile_website">
    <input class="string optional form-control" placeholder="http://your-website.com" type="text" name="profile[website]" id="profile_website">
  </div>

  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  <div class="form-group url optional profile_facebook_url">
    <input class="string url optional form-control" placeholder="http://facebook.com/your-account" type="url" name="profile[facebook_url]" id="profile_facebook_url">
  </div>

  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  <div class="form-group url optional profile_twitter_url">
    <input class="string url optional form-control" placeholder="http://twitter.com/your-account" type="url" name="profile[twitter_url]" id="profile_twitter_url">
  </div>

  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
  <div class="form-group url optional profile_instagram_url">
    <input class="string url optional form-control" placeholder="http://instagram.com/your-account" type="url" name="profile[instagram_url]" id="profile_instagram_url">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add profile">
</form>
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

#### Side note

Please note that I am using Ruby on Rails so my resulting code looks a bit blown up. The view code in slim is actually very concise:

```
i.fa.fa-link
= f.input :website, label: false

i.fa.fa-facebook
= f.input :facebook_url, label: false

i.fa.fa-twitter
= f.input :twitter_url, label: false

i.fa.fa-instagram
= f.input :instagram_url, label: false
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, an easy way to have an icon "within" a text input without having to try to use pseudo-elements with font awesome unicode etc, is to have the text input and the icon within a wrapper element which we will position relative, and then position both the search input and the font awesome icon absolute.

The same way we do with background images and text, we would do here. I feel this is good for beginners as well, as css positioning is something a beginner should learn in the beginning of their coding journey, so the code is easy to understand and reuse.

```
    <div class="searchbar-wrapper">
      <i class="fa fa-search searchbar-i" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input class="searchbar-input" type="search" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>

    .searchbar-wrapper{
      position:relative;
    }

    .searchbar-i{
      position:absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      padding: 0 .5rem;
    }

    .searchbar-input{
      padding-left: 2rem;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bootstrap 5.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    <div class="position-relative">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <a href=""><i class="position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle-y pe-2">❌</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on allcaps suggestion. Here is the font-awesome background method with the least amount of HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"><input></div>

.wrapper {
    position: relative; 
}

input { padding-left: 20px; }

.wrapper:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 3px;
    content: "\f007";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution to add a font-awesome icon inside the input element. Here is a simple code to add icon inside the input element. Just copy the code below and put where you want to add. or if you want to change the icon then just put your icon code in `<i>`  tag.

```css
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.soft-codeon {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ec008c, #fc6767); 
  color: white;
  min-width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.soft-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border:2px solid #fc6767;
}
.soft-field:focus {
  border: 2px solid #ec008c;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <div class="soft-codeon">
    <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
    <input class="soft-field" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrnm">
  </div>
  <div class="soft-codeon">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
    <input class="soft-field" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
```

Comment: The answer is helpful, but the sentence which is spam is not permitted. If you want to have something like that, you can put a link in your profile.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way ,but you need bootstrap**

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span> <!-- icon envelope "class="fa fa-envelope""-->
    </div>
    <input type="email" id="senha_nova" placeholder="Email">
  </div><!-- input-group -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make clickable icon to focus inside the text input element.

**CSS**

```
.myClass {
    font-size:20px;
    position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label style="position:relative;">
         <i class="myClass fa fa-address-book-o"></i>
         <input class="w3-input" type="text" style="padding-left:40px;">
    </label>
</div>
```

Just add whichever icon you like inside the `<i>` tag, from Font Awesome library and enjoy the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
.inp1{
color:#2E64FE;
width:350px;
height:35px;
border:solid;
font-size:20px;
text-align:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="inp1">          
<a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be more helpful to the OP if you also post some explanation about what this code block is doing!

Answer (score 0):

purely CSS

```
input[type=search] {
    min-width: 320px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    background-image: url('/img/search.png');
    background-size: 16px;
    background-position: 280px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

**My solution** was to have a relative container around the `input` for holding the icon. That outer container has a `::after` with the desired icon, positioned `absolute` within the container.

HTML:

```
<div class="button__outer">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send"/>
</div>
```

SASS code:

```
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
}

.button__outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;

    &::after {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       top: 0;
       height: 60px;
       line-height: 60px;
       width: 60px;
       font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
       content: "\f054";
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 27px;
       font-weight: 700;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the icon won't show up due to the Font Awesome version. For version 5, the css should be

```
.dropdown-wrapper::after {
     content: "\f078";
     font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
     font-weight: 900;
     color: #000;
     position: absolute;
     right: 6px;
     top: 10px;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 10%;
     height: 100%;
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below simple solution worked for me.

```
<input type="text" class="fa" placeholder="&#xf002; Search">
```

Use this filter for implement search: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
</head>
<style>
    .input {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 250px;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 9999px;
    }
    .message-input {
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="input">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        <input class="message-input" type="text" placeholder="Message">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this code addresses the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        /*background-color: #0e1d3033;*/
        content: "&#f00d;";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-weight: 900;
        -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button !important;
    }
    input#searchInput {
        -webkit-appearance: searchfield !important;
    }

<input data-type="search" type="search" id="searchInput" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score -3):

I tried the below stuff and it really works well
HTML

```css
input.hai {
    width: 450px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 15px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/casual-events-and-opinions/256/User-512.png') ;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div >

    <input class="hai" placeholder="Search term">

</div>
```

Comment: the question is about using font awesome icons

Answer (score -5):

To work this with unicode or fontawesome, you should add a `span` with `class` like below:

In HTML:

```
<span class="button1 search"></span>
<input name="username">
```

In CSS:

```
.button1 {
    background-color: #B9D5AD;
    border-radius: 0.2em 0 0 0.2em;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); 
    pointer-events: none;
    margin:1px 12px;    
    border-radius: 0.2em;    
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;           
}
```

Comment: this won't put the icon inside the text input

Answer (score -9):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ## Heading ##
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>
        Untitled Document
      </title>
      </head>
      <style>
        li {
          display: block;
          width: auto;
        }
        ul li> ul li {
          float: left;
        }
        ul li> ul {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
        }
        li:hover > ul {
          display: block;
          margin-left: 148px;
          display: inline;
          margin-top: -52px;
        }
        a {
          background: #f2f2ea;
          display: block;
          /*padding:10px 5px;
          */
          width: 186px;
          height: 50px;
          border: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
          border-bottom: none;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        li:hover >a {
          background: #ffffff;
        }
        ul li>li:hover {
          margin: 12px auto 0px auto;
          padding-top: 10px;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-top: 8px solid #c2c2c2;
        }
        .bottom {
          border-bottom: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
        }
        .sub_m {
          border-bottom: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
        }
        .sub_m2 {
          border-left: none;
          border-right: none;
          border-bottom: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
        }
        li.selected {
          background: #6D0070;
        }
        #menu_content {
          /*float:left;
          */

        }
        .ca-main {
          padding-top: 18px;
          margin: 0;
          color: #34495e;
          font-size: 18px;
        }
        .ca-sub {
          padding-top: 18px;
          margin: 0px 20px;
          color: #34495e;
          font-size: 18px;
        }
        .submenu a {
          width: auto;
        }
        h2 {
          text-align: center;
        }
      </style>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div id="menu_content">
                <h2 class="ca-main">
                  Item 1
                </h2>
              </div>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu" >
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="sub_m">
                  <div id="menu_content">
                    <h2 class="ca-sub">
                      Item 1_1
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>

                <a href="#" class="sub_m2">
                  <div id="menu_content">
                    <h2 class="ca-sub">
                      Item 1_2
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li >

                <a href="#" class="sub_m">
                  <div id="menu_content">
                    <h2 class="ca-sub">
                      Item 1_3
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>

            <a href="#">
              <div id="menu_content">
                <h2 class="ca-main">
                  Item 2
                </h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>

            <a href="#">
              <div id="menu_content">
                <h2 class="ca-main">
                  Item 3
                </h2>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li>

            <a href="#"  class="bottom">
              <div id="menu_content">
                <h2 class="ca-main">
                  Item 4
                </h2>
              </div>
            </a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </body>
</html>
```