# load icon in input(type=text) using placeHolder attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder

i have use the following code snippet

```
<input type="text" class="inputtext" style="margin: 2px;" placeholder="Search">
```

i have own font icons, i want to display the icon in the input through placeholder. How to use the content to display the icon in the input

I have refer the following stack overflow link

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285640/font-awesome-icon-inside-text-input-element)

but i can not achieve in my case . Is there any way to achieve this or  any other documentation link for display font icon in input?

Comment: *" i can not achieve in my case"*. Why ?

Comment: there is no `type="text"` in your example!!!

Comment: i have set the placeholder text as "\e66e; Search" and also             ::-moz-placeholder::before{font-family:'webfont';} but input will be displayed like "\e66e;search"  instead of icon

Comment: you want to put your own icon ?

Comment: yes i want to use my own icon

Comment: That link you have should of provided you with everything you need

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about adding a glyph icon and not a background image to your input, you will need to use either the `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements to inject and position one, howwever note that these are not available for `input` elements, so you will need to wrap your `input` within e.g. a `span`, then apply styling to this to add your placeholder icon. In the below example, I've simply added a small magnifying glass to the right hand side, though you can edit as appropriate.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsYL5/) (icon on right)

HTML

```
<span class='search'><input type="text" class="inputtext" style="margin: 2px;" placeholder="Search" /></span>
```

CSS

```
.search{
    display:inline-block;  
    position:relative;
}
.search:after{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
    color:grey;
    font-family:fontAwesome;
    content:'\f002';
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsYL5/2/) (icon on left)

If you want the icon to appear on the left of the input, you need some additional CSS trickery:

```
input{
    border:none;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.search {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.search:after {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:3px;
    top:3px;
    color:grey;
    font-family:fontAwesome;
    content:'\f002';
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsYL5/4/) (hiding the icon on focus)

If you wish to hide the icon on focus, you simply need to give the input a background color and a z-index with and without focus, the `:focus` z-index should be high enough to force it to the front to display over the icon.

CSS:

```
input{
    z-index:0;
    position:relative;
}
.search{
    display:inline-block;  
    position:relative;
}
.search:after{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
    color:grey;
    font-family:fontAwesome;
    content:'\f002';
}
input:focus{
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: provided Demo working fine but in my case i want to hide the icon while perform the editing

Answer (score 1):

check this <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gA4rx/81/)</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" class="inputtext" placeholder="Search">
```

#### CSS

```
input { 
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    background-image: url(http://www.levenmetwater.nl/static/global/images/icon-search.png);
    background-position: 10px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
input:focus {
    background-position: -20px center;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

---

Without `input:focus` 
<kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gA4rx/82/)**</kbd>