# Add a location marker glypphicon inside text input area

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Im using bootstrap and trying to add a location glyphicon marker inside a text input element

I tried adding the glypicon class to the input area like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" >
```

I follwed an example on W3Schools with botostrap glyphicons the example included the glyphicon marker inside a `<span>` element NOT inside a ` element, so I belief that os where my problem is.

IM trying to achieve the following  look:

[image]

[The example website where I got the image from](http://gzscripts.com/CarRentalScript/index.php?controller=GzPreview&action=index) uses the location marker as a background image in their css...

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64);
```

Any advice as to how to tackle this problem, much appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838964/add-bootstrap-glyphicon-to-input-box This link have a clear answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try implementing [this Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/map-marker/) icon inside the field - [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285640/font-awesome-icon-inside-text-input-element) a relevant question that will help you achieve your desired result.

```css
.wrapper input[type="text"] {
    position: relative; 
    }
    
    input { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; } /* This is for the placeholder */
    
    .wrapper:before {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        color:red;
        position: relative;
        left: -5px;
        content: "\f041";
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha256-uXf0U0UCIqBp2J3S53b28h+fpC9uFcA8f+b/NNmiwVk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<p class="wrapper"><input placeholder="&#61447; Username"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try It Once

```css
.areabox{
 width:auto; 
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
}
.areabox,.icon{
float:left;
}
.icon{
 color:#dddddd;
  font-size:18px;
  padding:5px;
}
.areabox input{
  border:0px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="areabox"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker icon"></span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Pickup Location"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I think this might work.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
    <label class="control-label">Pickup Location</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pickup Location" />
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
```