# Fontawesome in search bar

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to use the [search icon from fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/) instead of a `background-image` in my search bar that uses a transition to expand the input area. Clicking on this icon the area should be opend.

I tried with

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" name="eingabe" placeholder="Suche">
<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</input>
```

but then the symbol is beside the input and I can't click on it to use my transition to erase the width of my input.

@Saurav nearly solved my question, but I can't click on the icon.

```css
.search-bar {
  position: relative;
}

.search-bar .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.search-bar .input-text {
  width: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 35px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.search-bar .input-text:focus {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="search-bar">
  <i class="icon fa fa-search"></i>
  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="eingabe" placeholder="Suche">
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put icon inside input element in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

Comment: Please provide a live URL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285640/font-awesome-icon-inside-text-input-element

Comment: @flowerflower I've updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using a `div` (such as `.search-bar`) container inside which we can use a search icon with **CSS positioning** and search input and wrap it, to look it as a placeholder, Like:

```
<div class="search-bar">
  <i class="icon fa fa-search"></i>
  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="eingabe" placeholder="Suche">
</div>
```

You will also need a little **jQuery** (just for toggling the classes), and using `max-width` instead of width for `.input-text` like:

**JS (jQuery - for toggling 'active' class)**

```
$('.search-bar .icon').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

**CSS (when active class is toggled)**

```
.search-bar.active .input-text {
  max-width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
}
```

Have a look at the updated snippet below:

```js
$('.search-bar .icon').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.search-bar {
  position: relative;
}

.search-bar.active .input-text {
  max-width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
}

.search-bar .icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 13px 15px 13px 11px;
}

.search-bar .input-text {
  max-width: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-color: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 8px 6px 8px 35px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="search-bar">
  <i class="icon fa fa-search"></i>
  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="eingabe" placeholder="Suche">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like your first approach. Is their a way to activate my transition by clicking on the icon? (I edited my question above with the help of your code.)

Comment: @flowerflower I've updated my solution. Hope this is what you need to achieve. Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: I hoped for a solution without javascript but your code does what I described. Without javascript a can click anywhere outside the div for closing the input field. And with this javascript I have to click two times: first time to open and second time to set focus to write text in the input field.

Comment: you can set the focus on the input field after clicking the icon with javascript too.

Answer (score 4):

you need go to http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/ there you will be able to find Unicode for the icons. For example for search icon is `&#xf002;`

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

What you need to do is create a parent `div` around the `input` and use `div:before` to add the icon using `content`.

---

**CSS**

To get the icon that you want, you can refer to below url:

http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Take the first icon for example `[&#xf26e;]` to get this icon to show up in css, you will only require the last 4 characters with a backward slash like so `\f26e`

---

**Javascript (JQuery)**

To make the icon disappear when you focus the input you need some Javascript:

```
$( "input" )
  .focus(function() {
    $( this ).parent().addClass('active');
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $( this ).parent().removeClass('active');
  });
```

This will add/remove the .active class to your element and when it is active the css will overwrite and set the icon to diplay:none when blur it will return to normal.

```js
$( "input" )
  .focus(function() {
    $( this ).parent().addClass('active');
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $( this ).parent().removeClass('active');
  });
```

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  
}
div:before{
    content: "\f2b9";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
    color:grey;
}

input{
    padding: .5rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.active{
  
}

.active:before{
  display:none;
}

.active input{
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
<input type="text" name="eingabe" placeholder="placeholder text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is about clickable `font-awesome` icon inside `input` textbox, then check below snippet for simple one.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  console.log('search icon clicked!');
});
```

```css
.search-widget {
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
}

.search-widget input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  height: 35px;
}

.search-widget button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #1293D4;
  border: 0;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="search-widget">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="search">
  <button id="mybutton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to this link 
**http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/**
And find this code &#xf002