# How to add fa fa icons in text field, yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, font-awesome

Here's my code where I want to place fa fa icon in that.

Whenever I place `<i class=fa fa-user></i>` it not display anything and it runs without error's.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox() ?>
```

Comment: Did you add the font awesome CSS in head of that file..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome icon inside text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285640/font-awesome-icon-inside-text-input-element)

Comment: You can't put HTML tags inside of your text fields, it's looking for plaintext. But you can use their hexadecimal values. This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19285640/1527252

Comment: @GyandeepSharma thanks

Comment: I want to code in Yii framework, not in HTML.                                              
this is my code where i want icon in that.                                                     <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

Comment: did you check you console log in your browser to see if it is missing something?

Comment: is http://prntscr.com/h2zsbq ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your login view

```
 $fieldOptions3 = [
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-group has-feedback'],
        'inputTemplate' => "{input}<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback'></span>"
    ];
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password', $fieldOptions3)->label('Password')->passwordInput() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255, 'class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-lock']) ?>`