# Add labels to the top of colgroups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, colgroup

I have my colgroups generated dynamically and they style each group with a background color. Is there a way to add a label on top of each group?

My colgroup looks like this:

```
<colgroup>
  <col>
  <col span="3" style="background-color: #ccc;">
  <col span="3" style="background-color: #ddd;">
  <col span="3" style="background-color: #ccc;">
</colgroup>
```

And here is how it renders:
[image]

How do I put labels on top of each group? I can't select them to make that kind of change so maybe there is a jQuery API or even plugin for it?

Comment: Don't <col> tags need to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `:after` (or `:before`) pseudo class.

```
<col span="3" class="index">
```

CSS:

```
.index {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #ccc;

}

.index:after {
      position:absolute;          
      content: "Index";
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      color:#000000
}
```

You can also combine this with UTF-8 characters for any glyph you may want to use for your sort indicator.

See: [Use Font Awesome Icons in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css/14736642#14736642)

Comment: Good info on :after via CSS, but classes don't work with <col>.

Comment: I guess you can play Absolute Positioning Hell with the <table>. Oh well.

Comment: I ended up creating a thead on the fly based on the col spans. Something like this: $('colgroup col').each(function () { console.log(this); });