# Jquery contextmenu with bootstrap 3 glyphicons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, contextmenu

Have any one tried [jQuery-contextMenu](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) with Bootstrap icons?

Sample JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
            "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
        }
    });
});
```

is there any other way to create multilevel contextMenu in bootstrap??

Comment: This is perfect one to work with context menu in web

Comment: but it is not working since jQuerycontextMenu unable to found icon for the same, is there any way to add costume icon path?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kjLxwq88/1/ ?

Comment: thanks for sample code,but is there something better option than this?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the css in the jquery.contextMenu.css for the icon as specified in [Use Font Awesome Icons in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css)

Here is an example

Original

```
.context-menu-item.icon-edit {
  background-image: url(images/edit.png);
}
```

New

```
.context-menu-item.icon-edit {
    position: relative;
}
.context-menu-item.icon-edit:before {
    content:"\270f";
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu) link. This contextmenu is of type bootstrap so you will not get any problem while using it.Hope this Helps

Comment: Yah i have already tried this, but it doesn't support multilevel/submenus... :(

Comment: Than i can say that you have not done enough Reasearch on this. Have a look at [this](http://demo.code-abc.com/tcm/example/) sample, sub menu is working like charm

Comment: if i am not wrong both JS used on http://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu here  and in http://demo.code-abc.com/tcm/example sample provided by you are different.