# creating custom blocks in RStudio's bookdown

Tags: css, r, rstudio, bookdown

I'm experimenting with the great new package [`bookdown`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) to create a gitbook-style book using RMarkdown within RStudio. See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/).

My question is about creating [custom blocks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html). There is an example in the documentation of how to define a block style in a CSS file:

```
div.FOO {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

And the authors give some examples of what blocks might look like.

[image]

AFAIK, there is not an example of how to define this specific block with an icon. I don't know much about CSS, so looking for something I can modify.

I'd like to use [font awesome icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/comment/) like [Leanpub](https://leanpub.com/) does to create some special sidebars. Any ideas for creating something like this:

[image]

I think I would need to copy the fontawesome directory, specify the path to the included fontawesome css file (somewhere, not sure where), and use the `<i>` tag in my `div` definition, e.g., `<i class="fa fa-comment"></i>`. Not real clear on how to implement this though...or if it would even work.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I think the answer lies in https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/style.css You can see the custom divs at the top.

Comment: That's interesting, @Frank. Seeing `background: #f5f5f5 url("images/caution.png") left center/3em no-repeat;` led me to search for how to use fontawesome icons in CSS. Investigating this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css).

Comment: Using [this cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/), I see that the code for the comment icon is `fa-comment [&#xf075;]`. [This example](http://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/IjJzL) shows how to use `:after`, one of the suggestions in the SO answer I referenced. `#wrap:after { content: "\f075"; font-family: FontAwesome;}` I don't quite get how to use it yet, but seems like we're moving in the right direction.

Comment: Cool. I am not using fontawesome myself. Local copies of images work: http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/ (Scroll to the bottom.) I just copy-pasted Yihui's CSS and edited the file names and colors. (Icons taken from the link just above them.)

Comment: I might take this route instead. Thanks for sharing. Will post back if I learn enough about CSS to get the fontawesome idea over the finish line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to [@Frank's tip](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/style.css) (see [his solution](http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/) for using local images), I was able to come up with the following.

I added this to the `style.css` file in the root of my book's directory based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css) and [this specific example](http://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/IjJzL):

```
.rmdcomment {
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position:relative;
}

.rmdcomment:before {
    content: "\f075";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    left:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    font-size: 45px;
 }
```

I got the value `f075` for the comment icon from [this FontAwesome cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/).

Then I downloaded the [CSS toolkit from FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and copied the `font-awesome.min.css` file into the root of my book directory. I added the following to my `output.yml` file (in the template I started with, `style.css, toc.css` was already present):

```
bookdown::html_book:
  css: [style.css, toc.css, font-awesome.min.css]
```

Finally, I inserted a code chunk into my Rmd file using the `type` option:

````
```{block, type='rmdcomment'}
Some text for this block. Some text for this block. Some text for this block. Some text for this block. Some text for this block. Some text for this block.
```
````

[image]