# Some thing wrong in my CSS slider

Tags: html, css

I make a css slider in my website but I have a problem in the arrow slider, I don't know where's the problem, because when I make my slider first time All thinks are right but After refresh the page this's the result :'(

The problem is I can't see the arrow

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okPP9.jpg)

The slider code :

```css
content: '\e800';
```

this is the problem because it's not work in my website

Comment: Your snippet is not working, can you make it work? That would help us helping you.

Comment: You can't give us half the mark-up and expect anyone to be able to see them problem. The labels are for elements that aren't even included in the snippet e.g. `for="cs_slide1_0"`

Comment: @SimonArnold the problem is I can't see the arrows (see the picture) and about my code is very long, I can't make it here :'( because I have just 30.000 letters

Comment: @sayousaad You shouldn't paste all your code. The community expect you to isolate the problem as much at possible, so we can focus on helping you without having to know everything in your project.

Comment: @SimonArnold but I can't make it the website doesn't give to me the order :'( If you want I can send you the code in gmail

Comment: @DBS the problem is I can't see the arrows (see the picture) but when I make the slider in the first time all things is right but after that I have this problem :'(

Comment: @sayousaad I'm sorry, but StackOverflow is not about pasting all your code (or sending it by email) and asking people to debug it for you. You have to show that you've worked to solve the problem by yourself and ask specific questions on your blocker. Try to isolate the bug as mush as you can please.

Comment: @SimonArnold the problem is in the first time all things are right. I refresh my page I have this problem (can't see the arrow) you can see the picture in the post

Comment: @SimonArnold my problem is here : `content: '\e800';` what I need to show it in my website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've given us, it looks like you're using a font icon (maybe font awesome?) in a css :before or :after pseudo class. If this is the case, the reason your arrow is not showing is because you are not loading the font correctly. Firstly, you need to define the custom font on your page using `@font-face`. Many font icon sets, like Font Awesome, allow you to `@import` the css definition from a CDN. Once you have the font available for the page to use, you must define the font family you're using on the element to which you're adding the content.

This article may help you: [Use Font Awesome Icons in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css)

If it is still not working then you'll want to make sure that your browser supports custom fonts, most modern browsers do: http://caniuse.com/#search=%40font-face

Next time, please conduct a bit more research before posting a question.

Comment: Thank's and I make a other solution, I change '\e800' with '\2039'