# Adding font awesome from css

Tags: html, css

I added font awesome to my html but just figured that I would be better if add it through css instead because otherwise I'll have to add in each and every tag if I want it in multiple tags as my html code shows:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong><p>SERVICES</p></strong></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Financial</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Medical</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Insurance</a></li>   
</ul>
```

How can I add those icons from my style sheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Font Awesome Icons in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css)

Comment: You don't even tried to search... this is the first link found with google, took me 15s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by inserting FontAwesome icon `content` property inside of your CSS.

For example:

```
a:before { 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rakx/87/)

If you don't know how to get icon `content`, you can copy it from here:

[LINK](https://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

And after that you can assign this icon to specific `a` tag, consider using `a` `class` instead to make it more specific:

```
a.class_name:before { 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
```

Comment: Exactly... I did not know where to get the content.
I will probably have to save that page link cause I might need that until I dont know when.
Thanks Ivarz