# Font Awesome SVG Element With Use Tag Doesn't Cache

Tags: html, apache, svg, font-awesome, browser-cache

I wasn't certain if I should try asking on Serverfault or not, but I'll see if there are programing solutions first.

The "use" svg file in the following code does not cache on a Firefox 68esr browser:

```html
<svg class="smallwhiteicon"><use href="sprites/solid.svg#comments"></use></svg>
```

I've confirmed that:

- All the other files cache properly
- The [eTag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) for each file doesn't change upon page reload
- There's an ["Expires" header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) for all files on the page
- I've restarted the Apache httpd server instance several times
- I've tried messing around with the file being cached server side with [MMapFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_file_cache.html#MMapFile)
- Checked and double checked that SVGs are given expires headers

**Is there a different programming approach I should take to resolve the caching issue?**

I'm trying to optimize for speed, using about 5 different SVGs on the page.

I'm also *trying to avoid using font files* if possible (like the [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css) state).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While not the best answer I can give to my own question, this solution is probably the best I can hope for.

I changed the `<svg>` tag to a `<img>` and pointed to the svg I wanted:

```html
<img class="svgfilter" src="svgs/solid/comments.svg">
```

*While the file still doesn't cache* (somehow?) at least it is small enough that it wouldn't really matter:

[image]

Since I also wanted to [change the color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element) from black (as font awesome SVGs come like that) to white:

```css
.svgfilter {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```