# Where and how is bootstrap image stored?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

I downloaded the [bootstrap template](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2), but I can't figure out where the images are stored smile and tachometer. I have not found them among other svg images or other format.

It seems to me they are stored somehow differently, but a search on fa-tachometer-alt shows me the css files. Perhaps the image is drawn through css. But I don't understand how this is done?

[image]

Comment: This is not an image, this is font-awesmoe font-icon: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=smil&m=free

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Font Awesome Icons in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css)

Comment: @shuvo, alon-eitan many thanks guys! Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not an image itself its a webfont called font-awesome